# Ejabberd | Limit on maximum no of items in rosters list?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Is there any limit on maximum no of items in ejabberd rosters list? If so then where can I configure it.

Comment: Where are you find that ?

Comment: I don't think there is any limit on rosters list unless u r using ejabberd SaaS. You can put as many you want, though it is suggested not to put too many in the list b/c u may exhaust your server broadcasting presence info.

Comment: @dizballanzen sorry did not get you!

Answer (score 1):

As a default, there is not such limit in ejabberd Community edition.